# Shell/terminal/bash command or script for copying list of files from one project to another

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Let's say I have a project called my-project/ that lives in it's own directory and has the following file structure.

my-project/

```
.
├── src
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── normalize.js
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── Home
│   │       ├── index.js
│   │       └── assets
│   ├── static
│   ├── store
│   │   ├── createStore.js
│   │   └── reducers.js
│   └── styles
└── project.config.js
```

Now let's say I have a new project called my-new-project that also lives in it's own directory and has the same file structure as my-project but it contains an additional file called my-files-to-copy.txt

my-new-project/

```
.
├── src
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── normalize.js
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── Home
│   │       ├── index.js
│   │       └── assets
│   ├── static
│   ├── store
│   │   ├── createStore.js
│   │   └── reducers.js
│   └── styles
├── project.config.js
└── my-files-to-copy.txt # new file added to tree
```

my-new-project/ has the same file structure but different file contents than my-project/

Now let's say my-files-to-copy.txt contains a list of files I want to copy from my-project/ and write to the same path in my-new-project/ to overwrite the existing files in my-new-project/ at those locations.

my-files-to-copy.txt

```
src/main.js
src/routes/index.js
src/store/reducers.js
project.config.js
```

How can I accomplish this with a terminal/bash/shell command or script?

edit:

I think I might be able to do:

```
cp my-project/src/main.js my-new-project/src/main.js
cp my-project/src/routes/index.js my-new-project/src/routes/index.js
cp my-project/src/store/reducers.js my-new-project/src/store/reducers.js
cp my-project/project.config.js my-new-project/project.config.js
```

But as the number of files scales, this method will become less efficient. I was looking for a more efficient solution that would allow me to leverage the file that contains the list of files (or at least a script) without having to write a separate command for each one.

Comment: Maybe try using `rsync`...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `my-project` and `my-new-project` are on the same directory:

```
xargs -i -a my-new-project/my-files-to-copy.txt cp my-project/{} my-new-project/{}
```